# Nicolas Boubarki, Algebra I, Chapter 1, § 2, Ex. 12

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Nicolas Boubarki, Algebra I, Chapter 1, § 2, Ex. 12:

($E$ is a Semigroup with associative law (represented multiplicatively), $\gamma_a(x)=ax$.)

Under a multiplicative law on $E$, let $ a \in E $  be such that $\gamma_a $ is surjective.

(a) Show that, if there exists $u$ such that $ua=a$, then $ux=x$ for all $x\in E$.

(b) For an element $b\in E$ to be such that $ba$ is left cancellable, it is necessary and **sufficient** that $\gamma_a$ be surjective and that $b$ be left cancellable.

For those interested in part (a), simple proof is that for every $x\in E$ there exists $x^\prime \in E$ such that $ax^\prime=x$, consequently $ua=a \Rightarrow uax^\prime=ax^\prime \Rightarrow ux=x$.

In (b), surjectivity of $\gamma_a$ and left cancellability of $b$ is required.
**However, I am concerned with "sufficiency" portion of part (b).** When $E$ is infinite set there can always be a surjective function $\gamma_a$ which need not be injective, and left translation by $b$ is cancellable, however $ba$ need not be left cancellable.

Comment: Could you please post the full text of the exercise? In particular, what are $E$ and $\gamma_a$?

Comment: It seems, you inaccurately copied the problem.

Comment: @BorisNovikov - No, I copied correctly.

Comment: @Reetesh Mukul: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 3):

I have a Russian translation of Bourbaki. In it Ex.12 looks as follows:

"For $\gamma_{ba}$ to be an one-one mapping of $E$
**into**  $E$,  it is necessary and sufficient that $\gamma_{a}$ be an one-one mapping of
$E$ **onto**  $E$ and $\gamma_{b}$ be an one-one mapping of
$E$ **into**  $E$."

So I guess that there is a misprint in English  translation. I wonder how it looks in the French original?

Comment: It looks like this: "Pour qu'un élément $b\in E$ soit tel que $ba$ soit simplifiable à gauche, il faut et il suffit que $\gamma_a$ soit surjective et que $b$ soit simplifiable à gauche."

Comment: @A.P.: So it is equal to English text? Well, then there is a misprint in the translation from Russian into French :-)

Comment: @BorisNovikov - Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, note that $\gamma_c$ is injective iff $c$ is left cancellable, for some fixed $c\in E$. Thus the two formulations are equivalent.

Comment: @A.P.: Which two? F and R, or F and E?

Comment: The French and English ones are literal translations of each other. The Russian one is an equivalent formulation, given in terms of the maps $\gamma$.

Comment: @A.P.:No, in Russian formulation $\gamma_a$ is 1-1.

Comment: Actually, every map in the Russian formulation is 1-1, so I though it was some language oddity. Maybe not, after all...

Comment: @A.P.:I think the Russian translator corrected the misprint.

Comment: So, $\gamma_b$ being an one-one mapping of $E$ **onto** $E$ should mean that it is bijective? I am more worried about semantics.

Comment: @Reetesh Mukul:Yes.

Comment: Summarizing **necessity** part, when $ba$ is cancellable, $\gamma_a$ must be bijective. 

In Ex.13, Bourbaki is referring to this bijectivity property.

Comment: @Reetesh Mukul: Take into account that in Ex.12 before (a) the next is written: "Let $a$ be such that $\gamma_a$ is surjective".